# Xamarin, create a NuGet Package with .net Standard 2.0 and Dependecy Services

Tags: .net, xamarin, nuget

I'm creating a **NuGet** package using .Net Standard 2.0 with Xamarin, everything works great but now I need to create a ***Dependency Service*** that works with native code on iOS and Android, I can create the Interface but I can't create the implementation for iOS and Android because I don't have the **iOS/Android** project in my Solution.

There is a way to add i**OS/Android** solution so I can write my platform specific implementation? And how can I export it in my NuGet package?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your nuget package a seperate .netstandard2.0 class library? If so, are you using renderers? I cannot seem to import xamarin.platform.ios/droid into a seperate class library!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To export and iOS project as NuGet Package I've to go on ***Project->Options->NuGet Package->Build*** and check "Create a NuGet Package when building the Project".

I think this is the best solution.